# I need help with my Logitech M510 mouse

Tags: logitech, mouse-scroll, support

I have a Logitech M510 and I cant use the scroll button, and I cant find the software for it. I have already gone to the web site to look for software for for Ubuntu.

Comment: Mouse is working for other system or operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu (*or have access to another Windows machine*), install the Logitech Windows software for the `Unifying Receiver`, and their `Mouse software`. Any settings that you make in Windows will be remembered in Ubuntu. Here's the download link...

https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/options/Options_7.10.3.exe

If you don't have Windows, install [`Solaar`](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) in Ubuntu, and it'll give you ways to pair the Logitech mouse/keyboard, and many times, control some of the additional features of your mouse/keyboard.

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install solaar solaar-gnome3`

Comment: Im new to Ubuntu so are those commands to download Solaar?

Comment: My computer is dual boot and i had downloaded the software on windows.

Comment: @Looks_for_knowledge  The first link is for the Windows software. The two commands are for Ubuntu, and they'll install Solaar for you. The RED Solaar is a link to their web page for more info.

Comment: @Looks_for_knowledge please note my minor change to the last command to install Solaar.

Comment: This provided me with an application to view the accurate battery percentage over the Power Stats app in Linux Mint

Comment: Update, this did not work either, percentage always at 70% even with fully charged batteries.