# Logitech USB mouse works, but takes over a minute to initialize after starting X

Tags: usb, mouse, thinkpad, logitech

I have a logitech mouse attached to my thinkpad x270 via the dock.

When I boot my computer, X starts, but I am unable to use my mouse for about 1.5 minutes.

If I'm tailing the log while this is happening, this is what it looks like:

```
[    28.141] (**) Option "fd" "35"
[    28.142] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[    28.215] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4665
[    28.215] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    28.215] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[    29.154] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    29.156] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[    32.527] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 4480x1440
[    32.561] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (2560, 360), rotation normal, reflection none
[   156.842] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M510 (/dev/input/mouse3)
[   156.842] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   156.842] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   156.891] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M510 (/dev/input/event11)
[   156.891] (**) Logitech M510: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   156.891] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech M510'
[   156.892] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event11 13:75 fd 54 paused 0
[   156.892] (**) Logitech M510: always reports core events
[   156.892] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event11"
[   156.892] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   156.894] (II) event11 - Logitech M510: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   156.894] (II) event11 - Logitech M510: device is a pointer
[   156.894] (II) event11 - Logitech M510: device removed
[   156.894] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4.2/1-4.4.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0006/0003:046D:4051.0007/input/input22/event11"
[   156.894] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech M510" (type: MOUSE, id 20)
[   156.894] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   156.895] (**) Logitech M510: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   156.895] (**) Logitech M510: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   156.895] (**) Logitech M510: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   156.896] (II) event11 - Logitech M510: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   156.896] (II) event11 - Logitech M510: device is a pointer
```

As you can see, it does nothing from 32 to 156, where suddenly it decides it detects my mouse and starts working.

Why is it doing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks as though your mouse is initializing just fine. Look at `dmesg` and find out what is going on before the mouse initializes. The time between [    32.561]  [   156.842]. Something else may be taking a while to start before the system gets around to setting the mouse up.

Comment: Maybe helpfull https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116276/i-need-help-with-my-logitech-m510-mouse

Answer (score 1):

try

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

that will list things that are slowing startup. Then search for whatever is taking a long time (over 10 seconds)