# Logitech MX Anywhere 2 only works after delay after boot

Tags: usb, mouse, logitech

My Logitech MX Anywhere 2 is connected to my PC through it's proprietary dongle. To be able to (re-)pair the mouse to its dongle, I installed solaar (version 1.0.1).

After a cold boot into X11, solaar's GUi starts [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NIvT.png), the LED on the mouse lights up (green on top, white on the bottom), but it always seems to take a while until a move of the mouse results in a corresponding move of the mouse pointer on the screen or tapping the mouse buttons having any effect.

I did

> lsusb > lsusb_nomouse.txt

while the mouse was not reacting, and

> lsusb > lsusb_mouse.txt

after it had started to move the mouse pointer; however, a

> diff lsusb_mouse.txt lsusb_nomouse.txt

came up empty.  The best hint might be that a

> dmesg | grep -i logitech

ends in the following lines:

```
[    4.000528] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4063.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech MX Anywhere 2] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2:1
[    4.044111] input: Logitech Anywhere MX as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:1017.0005/input/input23
[    4.044475] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1017.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Anywhere MX] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2:2
[   30.676020] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4063.0004: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
```

The ~26sec delay between the last two messages seems to correspond to my waiting time.

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211854/logitech-usb-mouse-works-but-takes-over-a-minute-to-initialize-after-starting-x), I ran 'systemd-analyze blame'.  However, the first lines don't seem to have anything to do with the mouse:

```
46.705s fstrim.service                                       
 6.970s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
 6.575s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
 3.500s fwupd-refresh.service                                
 2.280s fwupd.service                                        
 1.727s mysql.service                                        
 1.345s gpu-manager.service
```

What can I do to make the delay go away? What is happening in those ~26sec? How could I diagnose this behaviour any further?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NIvT.png) [image: Solaar GUI with open context menu]

Comment: Do you have TWO Anywhere mice? In Solaar, un-pair BOTH mice, re-pair one, and see if that works. If not, un-pair the mouse again, boot into Windows, pair the mouse there using the Logitech software, reboot into Ubuntu, and see if it works. Does your Logitech dongle have the updated firmware?

Comment: @heynnema  Un-/repairing with solaar - didn't help. Un-/repairing with windows/logitech software - didn't help. Unpairing the other mouse - didn't help. :(

Comment: Does it work as expected in Windows? Did you do the firmware update? Update Solaar to 1.0.3 and see if that helps.

Comment: Is the dongle plugged directly into a computer USB port, or via a USB hub, or something else?

Comment: @heynnema it's plugged directly into the laptop.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions from the prior comment, from 23 hours ago.